# Simple code to get specific item from a list

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a list of `a` tags. I want to get an `a` tag which contains a string.
I used the below code and everything work fine.

```
string mainLink = "";
List<HtmlNode> dlLink = new List<HtmlNode>();
dlLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='links']//a").ToList();

foreach (var item in dlLink) {
  if (item.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("prefile"))
   {
     mainLink = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
   }
}
```

but I want to write a simple code

```
var dlLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='link']//a").ToList().Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("prefile")).ToList().ToString();
```

But it does not work and I get nothing.

Comment: How do you know you get nothing? What's the value of dlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` is setting mainLink string, but your linq chain is using `ToString` on a List result.

Converting your code, you will have something like this:

```
mainLink  = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='links']//a")
                            .Where(item => item.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("prefile"))
                            .Select(item => item.Attributes["href"].Value)
                            .Last();
```

I used `Select` to get only the `href` values, and getting the last as your `foreach` did, maybe you need to validate this last step, use a `LastOrDefault`, `First`, etc.

You can also use the `Last` or `First` instead of the `Where` condition:

```
mainlink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='links']//a")
                           .Last(item => item.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("prefile"))
                           .Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i get this error `  doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='downloadz']//a").Where(item => item.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("prefile")).Select(item => item.Attributes["href"].Value).Last() Evaluation of method System.Linq.Enumerable.Last(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>) calls into native method System.Globalization.TextInfo.InternalGetCaseInsHash(System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, string, string, bool, long). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported. string
`

Comment: @D.JCode You can check here https://dotnetfiddle.net/D7tv1l that both solution works. Maybe you can check your package version.